# Cannot find a way to close a toolbar. I believe it's the Templating toolbar

Tags: system, user-interface, templates, authortools

Today I was looking at the menu: Windows > Toolbar > Templating (and the others) which I was able to toggle show/hide but this one refuses to toggle. I hope I am not stuck with it. I noticed that although it shows it isn't highlighted in the top menu. This is not the characteristic behavior of menus. Is it a bug? How do I fix it?

The toolbar I want to remove is the one under the cyan or light blue strip
[image]

As you can see the menu isn't highlighted. I did everything I knew to do including spending hours searching through the documentation learning about toolbars and even how to make them even though I currently have no use for that.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should do the job:

```
SetOptions[
  EvaluationNotebook[]
, DockedCells  -> Inherited
, TaggingRules -> Inherited
, CellContext  -> Inherited
]
```

If you had any of those options customized prior clicking 'Templating' then use proper setting instead of `Inherited`.

Comment: it worked! thank you so much.